# Curve fitting with conditional equation

Tags: python, conditional-statements, curve-fitting

**Problem**
I have created a curve fitting exercise (see functional code below), but I would like to add to the functionality.
I need to be able to define the following condition:  `slope at min(xdata) = 0`.
(in words: *I want the fitted curve to start out with horizontal gradient*)

**What I have tried**
I have spent quite a bit of time researching [scipy.optimize.curve_fit](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) and evaluated other options ([lmfit package](https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/index.html), and scipy functions *scipy.optimize.fmin_slsqp*, *scipy.optimize.minimize*, etc.). lmfit only allows me to set a static condition on the parameters, such as p1 = 2 * p2 + 3. But it does not allow me to address min(xdata) dynamically, and I cannot make use of the derivate in the constraint.
Scipy only allows me to minimize the function (find an optimal x, but parameters p are already known). Or it can be used to define a specific range for the parameters. I was not able to define a second function that can be used to constrain the parameters during the curve fitting.

I need to be able to pass the condition directly to the curve fitting algorithm (rather than addressing the problem by bringing the condition into the `cubic_fit()` equation - it seems possible to eliminate e.g. p3 and define it as a combination of the other parameters and min(xdata)). My actual fitting function is much more complex and I need to run this script iteratively on a batch of data (varying min(xdata)). I cannot manually alter the fitting function each time...

I am grateful for any suggestions, maybe there are other packages out there that allow for a more complex definition of the curve fitting problem?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.stats
import scipy.optimize

# generate dummy data - on which I will run a curve fit below
def cubic_fit_with_noise(x, p1, p2, p3, p4):
    return p1 + p2*x + p3*x**2 + p4*x**3 + np.random.rand()

xdata = [x * 0.1 for x in range(0, 100)]
ydata = np.array( [cubic_fit_with_noise (x, 2, 0.4, -.2,0.02) for x in xdata] )

# now, run the curve-fit

#  set up the fitting function: 
def cubic_fit(x, p1, p2, p3, p4):
    return p1 + p2*x + p3*x**2 + p4*x**3

# define starting point:
s1 = 2.5
s2 = 0.2
s3 = -.2
s4 = 0.02

# scipy curve fitting:
popt, pcov = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(cubic_fit, xdata, ydata, p0=(s1,s2,s3,s4))
y_modelled = np.array([cubic_fit(x, popt[0], popt[1], popt[2], popt[3]) for x in xdata])

print(popt)     # prints out the 4 parameters p1,p2,p3,p4 defined in curve-fitting

plt.plot(xdata, ydata, 'bo')
plt.plot(xdata, y_modelled, 'r-')
plt.show()
```

The above code runs with Python3 (fix the print statement if you have Python2). 
As an addition, I want to bring in the derivative:

```
def cubic_fit_derivative(x, p1, p2, p3, p4):
    return p2 + 2.0 * p3 * x + 3 * p4 * x**2
```

and the constraint that `cubic_fit_derivative(min(xdata), p1,p2,p3,p4) = 0`.

Comment: quick guess fit `a * (x - xmin)**2 * (x - b)` or something like this

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, everyone. The suggestions I see below all seem to work (at the time of writing). I have accepted the one by @Newville as the answer as it has the clearest approach and is highly versatile, so can easily be adopted for more complex tasks.

Comment: I agree, though I can tell from experience: Don't fit with constraints if you don't have to.

Comment: @mikuszefski in other words, if you have to use constraints, use them. ;). In this case, the constraint simply removes a variable parameter from the fit.  One could have altered the objective function to impose `p2  = -p3*xmin - 3*p4*xmin**2`, and used only three variables (p1, p3, p4), but that's not a very general approach.  In a sense, the model function always does impose a constraint on the fit.  The approach described with lmfit just makes it easier to adjust what values the parameter take.

Comment: @MNewville I never doubted that the constraints-approach is very general and powerful. Yet, depending on the type of constraint and the size of your data set, computationally it can be very painful. From that point of view you gave the right answer to the wrong question. A third order polynomial with slope zero at `x0` is just a polynomial where the homogeneous part has a twin root at `x0`. No need for any constraints, just simple maths and just a simple fit. On the other hand, we do not know what the OP's true problem is, and it might be very different from a third order polynomial. Cheers.

Comment: In addition to the polynomials, I am fitting cosine and logistic functions. Furthermore, the `min(xdata)` varies. And, I actually need to define that the derivative is negative (rather than just setting it to zero). All of that is possible with the solution provided by @MNewville - thanks again

Comment: Thank's for the info. Me and @MNewville just having a nice discussion here (knowing that comments are not made for that). That `xmin` is varying is considered in all solutions here. Moreover, I am quite confident that you can formulate your constraint in a 'non-constaint' way, although it will be much less straight forward than your chosen solution. (Would be nice if you provide the actual function, just to fiddle around for fun) Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your condition that the derivative of your polynomial = 0 at `xmin` can be expressed as a simple constraint and means that the variables `p2`, `p3`, and `p4` are not actually independent. The derivate condition is

```
p2 + 2*p3*xmin + 3*p4*xmin**2 = 0
```

where `xmin` is the minimum value of `xdata`.  Furthermore, `xmin` will be known prior to the fit (if not necessarily when your script is written), you can use this to constrain one of the three parameters.   Since `xmin` may be zero (in fact, it is for your case), the constraint should be that

```
p2 = - 2*p3*xmin - 3*p4*xmin**2
```

Using lmfit, the original, unconstrained fit would look like this (I cleaned it up a bit):

```
import numpy as np
from lmfit import Model
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

#  the model function:
def cubic_poly(x, p1, p2, p3, p4):
    return p1 + p2*x + p3*x**2 + p4*x**3

xdata = np.arange(100) * 0.1
ydata = cubic_poly(xdata, 2, 0.4, -.2, 0.02)
ydata = ydata + np.random.normal(size=len(xdata), scale=0.05)

# make Model, create parameters, run fit, print results
model  = Model(cubic_poly)
params = model.make_params(p1=2.5, p2=0.2, p3=-0.0, p4=0.0)
result = model.fit(ydata, params, x=xdata)
print(result.fit_report())

plt.plot(xdata, ydata, 'bo')
plt.plot(xdata, result.best_fit, 'r-')
plt.show()
```

which prints:

```
[[Model]]
    Model(cubic_poly)
[[Fit Statistics]]
    # function evals   = 13
    # data points      = 100
    # variables        = 4
    chi-square         = 0.218
    reduced chi-square = 0.002
    Akaike info crit   = -604.767
    Bayesian info crit = -594.347
[[Variables]]
    p1:   2.00924432 +/- 0.018375 (0.91%) (init= 2.5)
    p2:   0.39427207 +/- 0.016155 (4.10%) (init= 0.2)
    p3:  -0.19902928 +/- 0.003802 (1.91%) (init=-0)
    p4:   0.01993319 +/- 0.000252 (1.27%) (init= 0)
[[Correlations]] (unreported correlations are <  0.100)
    C(p3, p4)                    = -0.986 
    C(p2, p3)                    = -0.967 
    C(p2, p4)                    =  0.914 
    C(p1, p2)                    = -0.857 
    C(p1, p3)                    =  0.732 
    C(p1, p4)                    = -0.646
```

and produces a plot of
[image]

Now, to add your constraint condition, we will add `xmin` as a fixed parameter, and constrain `p2` as above, replace the above with:

```
params = model.make_params(p1=2.5, p2=0.2, p3=-0.0, p4=0.0)

# add an extra parameter for `xmin`
params.add('xmin', min(xdata), vary=False)

# constrain p2 so that the derivative is 0 at xmin
params['p2'].expr = '-2*p3*xmin - 3*p4*xmin**2'

result = model.fit(ydata, params, x=xdata)
print(result.fit_report())

plt.plot(xdata, ydata, 'bo')
plt.plot(xdata, result.best_fit, 'r-')
plt.show()
```

which now prints

```
[[Model]]
    Model(cubic_poly)
[[Fit Statistics]]
    # function evals   = 10
    # data points      = 100
    # variables        = 3
    chi-square         = 1.329
    reduced chi-square = 0.014
    Akaike info crit   = -426.056
    Bayesian info crit = -418.241
[[Variables]]
    p1:     2.39001759 +/- 0.023239 (0.97%) (init= 2.5)
    p2:     0          +/- 0        (nan%)  == '-2*p3*xmin - 3*p4*xmin**2'
    p3:    -0.10858258 +/- 0.002372 (2.19%) (init=-0)
    p4:     0.01424411 +/- 0.000251 (1.76%) (init= 0)
    xmin:   0 (fixed)
[[Correlations]] (unreported correlations are <  0.100)
    C(p3, p4)                    = -0.986 
    C(p1, p3)                    = -0.742 
    C(p1, p4)                    =  0.658
```

and a plot like

[image]

If `xmin` had not been zero (say, `xdata = np.linspace(-10, 10, 101)`, the value and uncertainty of `p2` would not be zero.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment, you just have to fit the right function. I forgot the constant, though. So the function would be `a*(x-xmin)**2*(x-xn)+c`

As `curvefit` does not take additional parameters as would e.g. `leatssq`, the only trick is to pass `xmin`. I do that by a global variable (Maybe not the nicest way, but it works. Comments on how to do it better are welcome). 
Eventually, you just need to add the following lines to your code:

```
def cubic_zero(x,a,xn,const):
    global xmin
    return (a*(x-xmin)**2*(x-xn)+const)
```

and

```
xmin=xdata[0]
popt2, pcov2 = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(cubic_zero, xdata, ydata)
y_modelled2 = np.array([cubic_zero(x, *popt2) for x in xdata])

print(popt2)

plt.plot(xdata, y_modelled2, color='#ee9900',linestyle="--")
```

providing

```
>>>[ 0.01429367  7.63190327  2.92604132]
```

and

[image: With zero slope fit]

Comment: BTW (I am sure you can calculate yourself but ...) the original parameters `p1,...,p4` are `[ -popt2[0]*xmin**2*popt2[1]+popt2[2],popt2[0]*(xmin**2+2*xmin*popt2[1]),-popt2[0]*(2*xmin+popt2[1]),popt2[0]  ]`

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses `scipy.optimize.leastsq`. Using the self made `residuals` function, there is actually no need to pass `xmin` as additional parameter to the fit. The fit function is as in the other post and therefore has no necessity for constraints. This looks like:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import leastsq

def cubic_fit_with_noise(x, p1, p2, p3, p4):
    return p1 + p2*x + p3*x**2 + p4*x**3 + .2*(1-2*np.random.rand())

def cubic_zero(x,a,xn,const, xmin):
    return (a*(x-xmin)**2*(x-xn)+const)


def residuals(params, dataX,dataY):
    a,xn,const=params
    xmin=dataX[0]
    dist=np.fromiter( (y-cubic_zero(x,a,xn,const, xmin) for x,y in zip(dataX,dataY)), np.float)
    return dist

xdata = np.linspace(.5,10.5,100)
ydata = np.fromiter( (cubic_fit_with_noise (x, 2, 0.4, -.2,0.02) for x in xdata), np.float )

# scipy curve fitting with leastsq:
initialGuess=[.3,.3,.3]
popt2, pcov2, info2, msg2, ier2 = leastsq(residuals,initialGuess, args=(xdata, ydata), full_output=True)

fullparams=np.append(popt2,xdata[0])
y_modelled2 = np.array([cubic_zero(x, *fullparams) for x in xdata])

print(popt2) 
print(pcov2)
print np.array([ -popt2[0]*xdata[0]**2*popt2[1]+popt2[2],popt2[0]*(xdata[0]**2+2*xdata[0]*popt2[1]),-popt2[0]*(2*xdata[0]+popt2[1]),popt2[0]  ])

plt.plot(xdata, ydata, 'bo')
plt.plot(xdata, y_modelled2, 'r-')
plt.show()
```

and provides:

```
>>>[ 0.01710749  7.69369653  2.38986378]
>>>[[  4.33308441e-06   5.61402017e-04   2.71819763e-04]
    [  5.61402017e-04   1.10367937e-01   5.67852980e-02]
    [  2.71819763e-04   5.67852980e-02   3.94127702e-02]]
>>>[ 2.35695882  0.13589672 -0.14872733  0.01710749]
```

*Image upload does not work at the moment ... for whatever reason but result is the same as in the other post*